# How to call and keep the json string from fetch() before render of object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a hard time to call `fetch()` from a small `React` app.

The idea is to

1. have a `class` (so I can reuse it)
2. call `fetch` to get `json-data` from the server
3. populate it with the data fetched from a server.

The `class` looks like:

```
import React from 'react';

class GetJsonData extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
    id: this.props.id,
    content: this.props.content
  };
}

render() {
    return <h2>Id: {this.state.id + ' content: ' + this.state.content} </h2> 
    ;
  }
}


export default GetJsonData;
```

The index.js looks like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import GetJsonData from './GetJsonData'

var jsonString = '{\n'+
'"id":"1",\n'+ 
'"content":"Returning Weblogic JSON 2022-08-07 08:56:34"\n'+
'}';

const data = JSON.parse(jsonString)

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<GetJsonData id={data.id} content={data.content} />);
```

I have tried to add a function to `index.js` but in some how I can not return the `string` from the server I have for eg tried the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import GetJsonData from './GetJsonData'

var jsonString = '{\n'+
'"id":"1",\n'+ 
'"content":"Returning Weblogic JSON 2022-08-07 08:56:34"\n'+
'}';

jsonString = getJson();

const data = JSON.parse(jsonString)

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<GetJsonData id={data.id} content={data.content} />);


function getJson() {

  var retvalue;
  const API = 'http://127.0.1.1:7001/weblogic-rest-facade/resources/rest-facade/get-json';

    fetch(API)
   .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((json) => {
    retvalue = JSON.stringify(json);
    alert('retvalue_1: ' + retvalue);
    
  })

  alert('retvalue_2: ' + retvalue);  
return retvalue;

}
```

It seems like the alert with 'retvalue_2: ' always executes first, to me that is very strange.

So if you guys got any clue how to get the `json-string` before it is needed for render please let me know.
Best regards
Fredrik

Comment: Maybe try using life cycles? like [componentWillMount()](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-componentwillmount)

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is a async function. So the callback you define in `then` method is executed whenever the promise that `fetch` returns is fulfilled and successful. Javascript does not wait for your async function to finish and runs rest of the code, executes `alert`. If you want Javascript to wait for the response, use an `async` function and `await` to wait for the request response. You can learn more by reading about async functions, promises, await in Javascript.